# How to convert .crt to .pem

Tags: x509, pem, asn.1, crt, der

How can I convert .crt to .pem?

Comment: This is my [gist](https://gist.github.com/tuansoibk/0b1f279be5c1b782d95f4e15af1442cb) that explains different cryptography file formats, how to recognise and convert them from one format to/from another.

Answer (score 607, accepted):

You can do this conversion with [the OpenSSL library](http://www.openssl.org/). Windows binaries can be found [here](http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html).

Once you have the library installed, the command you need to issue is:

```
openssl x509 -in mycert.crt -out mycert.pem -outform PEM
```

Comment: @Dave, this is generally equivalent to `cp mycert.crt mycert.pem`. Since the default `-inform` is `PEM`, this is just doing an in->out conversion from PEM to PEM. The main different might be in potential text headers around the actual cert. Most of the time `.crt` are in PEM format anyway, but sometimes they're in DER format (the conventions are not always well established).

Comment: I had to use the line "openssl x509 -in myCert.crt -inform der -outform pem -out myCert.pem" to get it interpreted correctly.

Comment: Didn't work for me, the certificate apparently needs to contain intermediate certificates.

Comment: I am at loss why so misleading answer has so many up votes. "crt" is just a part of file name and has nothing to do with format, which may be DER or PEM. Only if you know the format, you can use above mentioned command with proper options.

Comment: The above command has just generated a .pem with the same content as the .crt file. So, I think Dave is right.. could have just copy pasted the file with .pem extension at list in my case!

Comment: .crt files may already be in PEM format (in which case the answer above will work, or a simple copy which does the exact same thing). Or, they may be in DER format, in which case the above answer won't work, and you need to add `-inform DER` as other comments and answers have noted.

Comment: not working for me. Getting: unable to load certificate
4724020844:error:09FFF06C:PEM routines:CRYPTO_internal:no start line:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22.240.1/libressl-2.6/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:683:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE. solution below by Anil G worked though

Comment: Downvoted as the answer does not work for a large percentage of people, it should be edited to suggest the correct `-inform` value.

Comment: For anyone reading these comments, you can use this to determine which format your .crt is in before you convert to .pem https://www.ssl.com/guide/pem-der-crt-and-cer-x-509-encodings-and-conversions/

Answer (score 250):

I found the [other OpenSSL answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4691749/442760) didn't work for me, but the following did, working with a CRT file sourced from windows.

```
openssl x509 -inform DER -in yourdownloaded.crt -out outcert.pem -text
```

Comment: Worked perfect, thanks. Seems some crt files are binary (DER) encoded and others are base64 encoded like pem.

Comment: worked like charm, thank you! solution above did not work, see my comment there on details. using Mac OS

Comment: I had a situation where I needed to convert several files. Used a loop in Bash with parameter expansion to create the `.pem` extension from each original file name.

    `for f in *.crt ; do openssl x509 -in "$f" -outform PEM -out "${f%.*}.pem" ; done`

It will transform, for example, `file1.crt`, `file2.crt` to `file1.pem` and `file2.pem`.