# JBoss 7 and Apache SSL

Tags: ssl, apache2, jboss7.x, keytool

I read this tutorial "http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/7.0.x/ssl-howto.html"
and i already have *JBoss Server* with SSL.

I want to use current cert.

```
(what i generate by "keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA")
```

in Apache 2 (as Front-end for JBoss).

But i don't know how to convert key from keytool in PEM (key and cer files). How do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has already been answered. Please check the answers for the same questions:
[how to convert CRT to PEM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691699/how-to-convert-crt-to-pem)
and or:
[How to make PEM from KEY and CRT files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991758/how-to-get-an-openssl-pem-file-from-key-and-crt-files)