# How do I "package" a Python script with openssl?

Tags: python, openssl, package, ssl-certificate, py2exe

I have a large folder containing X.509 certificates (.cer files), some of which are encoded in Base64 format and some of which are in DER format.  I want them all to be in Base64 format so I can open them in a text editor and see the BEGIN CERTIFICATE and END CERTIFICATE stuff and not just a bunch of gibberish.

I did some searching and found stuff like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691699/how-to-convert-crt-to-pem) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991758/how-to-get-an-openssl-pem-file-from-key-and-crt-files) which gives me hope because I just write a Python script like:

```
for cert in os.listdir("/path/to/certificate/dir"):
    openssl x509 -in cert -out newcert.cer -outform PEM
```

Now the issue is that I need other folks to do this on multiple computers (on Windows) and instead of requiring them all to download the [Win32 OpenSSL executable](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html), I want to simply package up my script into an executable that I can hand off to these folks and have it run and convert everything.

I'm new to packaging concepts so forgive me if I can ask wrong or stupid-sounding questions but is there a way to package up the `openssl` library along with my Python script into an executable?  If so, can someone point me on the right path?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I've only packaged once using `py2exe`.

**EDIT 2:**

I'm still stuck on how to do this.  FWIW, I have a Windows 8 machine with Python 2.7 installed, and a folder containing X.509 certs in a mixture of base64 or DER encoded format that I want to convert all to base64 encoding.  I downloaded the `Win64OpenSSL_Light-1_0_1f.exe` from the Shining Light Productions website.  I installed it, navigated to the created directory and the `bin` folder in which is the `openssl.exe` command.  Then, in the command prompt, I typed:

```
openssl x509 -in INPUT.cer -out OUTPUT.cer -outform PEM
```

and I got the error:

```
unable to load certificate
4716:error:blahblah:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:.\crypto\pem\pem_lib.c:703 Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

The `INPUT.cer` is in DER encoding.  I understand that the cert is not trusted but I don't really care about that right now (I don't want to have to install each of the certs into my trusted cert store). I just want to convert it to Base64 if possible.  In other words, I want to automate the process of opening up each individual .cer file, going to the `Details` tab, clicking `Copy to File`, going through the export wizard and selecting to export it as a Base64 encoding.

**EDIT 3:**

Okay, so [this link](http://info.ssl.com/article.aspx?id=12149) helped me out tremendously.  I got the conversion to work.  Yay.  Now, I still need to figure out how to "package" this OpenSSL with my `py2exe` so that I can run the command over and over again.

**EDIT 4:**

Here is my `setup.py` file.

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
from glob import glob
import sys

data_files = [("Microsoft.VC90.CRT", glob(r'C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.1_none_e163563597edeada\*.*'))]


sys.path.append("C:\\Windows\\WinSxS\\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.1_none_e163563597edeada")

setup(
    data_files = data_files,
    console=['myscript.py']
)
```

I usually run `py2exe setup.py` which creates the `dist` and `build` folders.  It packages up everything and creates a `myscript.exe` that I can run.  What do I need to do to get it to include the OpenSSL binaries?

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something. Rather than packaging OpenSSL, why not just package the certs that you have converted to PEM?

Comment: @noloader: thanks for your comment.  my scenario is that I have other coworkers who have many __different__ certs on their machines so I am trying to deploy a script that will convert them all to base64.  I don't necessarily know what they have.