# Verify a certificate chain using openssl verify

Tags: openssl, certificate

I'm building a own certificate chain with following componenents:

```
Root Certificate - Intermediate Certificate - User Certificate
```

Root Cert is a self signed certificate, Intermediate Certificate is signed by Root and User by Intermediate.

Now I want to verify if a User Certificate has its anchor by Root Certificate.

With

```
openssl verify -verbose -CAfile RootCert.pem Intermediate.pem
```

the validation is ok. In the next step I validate the User Cert with

```
openssl verify -verbose -CAfile Intermediate.pem UserCert.pem
```

and the validation shows

```
error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 282):

From `verify` documentation:

> If a certificate is found which is its own issuer it is assumed to be the root CA.

In other words, root CA needs to be self signed for verify to work. This is why your second command didn't work. Try this instead:

```sh
openssl verify -CAfile RootCert.pem -untrusted Intermediate.pem UserCert.pem
```

It will verify your entire chain in a single command.

Comment: I'm up-voting this answer as I recently had to do this and after trying different options listed by `man verify`, I found that the `-untrusted` parameter is the correct one to use when specifying the intermediate certificate.

Comment: I think the second answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31205833/173062 is more accurate - it passes the chain of certificates to the -CAfile parameter.

Comment: `-untrusted` doesn't check whether certificate chain is fully valid. Please consider to pass both intermediate and root to command as `-CAfile` as other questions suggests.

Comment: Use -untrusted for Intermediate.pem if it is possible that the following happens: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/cryptography-dev/2016-August/000676.html

Comment: That's not what OP asked for, but in case you want to verify NOT self-signed chain, then use system/browser CA file instead of your own. For example on OS X with openssl from homebrew use: `openssl verify -CAfile /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem -untrusted Intermediate.pem UserCert.pem`

Comment: The '-show_chain' option turned out to be helpful, after concatinating root and intermediates:
`openssl verify -show_chain -CAfile inetmediates-and-root.pem UserCert.pem`

Comment: I vote for this answer, for the OP case both way get OK, but for the case below:
Root CA (self signed)
Intermediate CA (self signed)  --> User Certificate(Intermediate signed)

This command will get failed and Peter`s command will get OK.
And I think OP want to also verify that

Comment: @Glenjamin This is not true. RootCert.pem file can contain whole chain. Second answer just provides a chain explicitly. Anyway Intermediate.pem also can consist of a list of certificates.

Answer (score 78):

That's one of the few legitimate jobs for `cat`:

```
openssl verify -verbose -CAfile <(cat Intermediate.pem RootCert.pem) UserCert.pem
```

---

Update:

As Greg Smethells points out in the comments, **this command implicitly trusts Intermediate.pem**. I recommend reading the first part of [the post Greg references](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/cryptography-dev/2016-August/000676.html) (the second part is specifically about pyOpenSSL and not relevant to this question).

In case the post goes away I'll quote the important paragraphs:

> Unfortunately, an "intermediate" cert that is actually a root / self-signed
>   *will be treated as a trusted CA* when using the recommended command given
>   above:
>
> $ openssl verify -CAfile <(cat geotrust_global_ca.pem rogue_ca.pem)
>   fake_sometechcompany_from_rogue_ca.com.pem
>   fake_sometechcompany_from_rogue_ca.com.pem: OK

It seems openssl will stop verifying the chain as soon as a root certificate is encountered, which may also be Intermediate.pem if it is self-signed. In that case RootCert.pem is not considered. So make sure that Intermediate.pem is coming from a trusted source before relying on the command above.

Comment: Will this actually verify the intermediate cert against the root cert?

Comment: It does. I just re-ran the commands with a chain that I know is correct (it serves production traffic for my employer), and then again with another, unrelated root certificate. See [the transcript gist](https://gist.github.com/pschultz/528864ec770e6469cab3c85418b34ab7).

Comment: Thanks, was wondering about the order of concatenation, which apparently varies with tooling.

Comment: WARNING: do *NOT* use this if Intermediate.pem is at all untrusted. For more info read here: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/cryptography-dev/2016-August/000676.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, Greg. When I gave the answer, I downloaded both roots and intermediates from the issuers' homepages, so the thought didn't occur to me. I have updated the answer to make clear that the intermediate is implictly trusted with this command.

Comment: downvoted because intermediates should be added with the `-untrusted` option

Comment: Same command works with `openssl verify -CAfile RootCert.pem -untrusted <(cat Intermediate1.pem Intermediate2.pem) UserCert.pem` in the case of multiple untrusted intermediates.

Comment: @davenpcj or just use `-untrusted` option multiple times. from man _This option can be specified more than once to include untrusted certificates from multiple files_. `openssl verify -CAfile RootCert.pem -untrusted Intermediate1.pem -untrusted Intermediate2.pem UserCert.pem`

Comment: openssl ver. 1.0.2r Feb 2019 requires the use of the `-untrusted` flag for the Intermediate.pem so the concatenation using `cat` did not work for me. Needed `openssl verify -verbose -CAfile ./ROOT-CA.pem -untrusted ./INTERMEDIATE-CA.pem webCert.pem`

Comment: @Peter I get `error 2 at 1 depth lookup:unable to get issuer certificate` using this answer while getting `OK` using @Priyadi's answer. Any ideas?

Comment: @somenickname, see Tony's comment. The -untrusted option is preferable anyway. I suggest you ask your own question if you want further help. Comments aren't the right place to debug your problem.

Comment: How can an "intermediate" cert be self-signed? If it's a self-signed CA, surely it's a root cert, not an intermediate cert. As such, unless I miss something, using it as a CAfile (trusted) should mean it's trusted [feature], using it as an intermediate (untrusted) should have no effect because the cert that proves it is OK is itself [not a bug].

Comment: To answer my own comment, the concern is that an intermediate cert might not really be an intermediate cert - adding the cert to -CAfile, instead of to -untrusted, allows an attacker to short-circuit the certificate chain. It's misleading to say the command 'implicitly trusts the intermediate cert', more accurate to say that it 'explicitly trusts the intermediate cert'.

Answer (score 20):

The problem is, that `openssl -verify` does not do the job.

[As Priyadi mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26520714/490291), `openssl -verify` stops at the first self signed certificate, hence you do not really verify the chain, as often the intermediate cert is self-signed.

> I assume that you want to be 101% sure, that the certificate files are correct before you try to install them in the productive web service.  This recipe here performs exactly this pre-flight-check.

Please note that [the answer of Peter is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31205833/490291), however the output of `openssl -verify` is no clue that everything *really* works afterwards.  Yes, it might find some problems, but quite not all.

Here is a script which does the job to verify a certificate chain before you install it into Apache.  Perhaps this can be enhanced with some of the more mystic OpenSSL magic, but I am no OpenSSL guru and following works:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This Works is placed under the terms of the Copyright Less License,
# see file COPYRIGHT.CLL.  USE AT OWN RISK, ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. 
#
# COPYRIGHT.CLL can be found at http://permalink.de/tino/cll
# (CLL is CC0 as long as not covered by any Copyright)

OOPS() { echo "OOPS: $*" >&2; exit 23; }

PID=
kick() { [ -n "$PID" ] && kill "$PID" && sleep .2; PID=; }
trap 'kick' 0

serve()
{
kick
PID=
openssl s_server -key "$KEY" -cert "$CRT" "$@" -www &
PID=$!
sleep .5    # give it time to startup
}

check()
{
while read -r line
do
    case "$line" in
    'Verify return code: 0 (ok)')   return 0;;
    'Verify return code: '*)    return 1;;
#   *)  echo "::: $line :::";;
    esac
done < <(echo | openssl s_client -verify 8 -CApath /etc/ssl/certs/)
OOPS "Something failed, verification output not found!"
return 2
}

ARG="${1%.}"
KEY="$ARG.key"
CRT="$ARG.crt"
BND="$ARG.bundle"

for a in "$KEY" "$CRT" "$BND"
do
    [ -s "$a" ] || OOPS "missing $a"
done

serve
check && echo "!!! =========> CA-Bundle is not needed! <========"
echo
serve -CAfile "$BND"
check
ret=$?
kick

echo
case $ret in
0)  echo "EVERYTHING OK"
    echo "SSLCertificateKeyFile $KEY"
    echo "SSLCertificateFile    $CRT"
    echo "SSLCACertificateFile  $BND"
    ;;
*)  echo "!!! =========> something is wrong, verification failed! <======== ($ret)";;
esac

exit $ret
```

> Note that the output after `EVERYTHING OK` is the Apache setting, because people using `NginX` or `haproxy` usually can read and understand this perfectly, too ;)

There is a [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/hilbix/bde7c02009544faed7a1) of this which might have some updates

Prerequisites of this script:

- You have the trusted CA root data in `/etc/ssl/certs` as usual for example on Ubuntu
- Create a directory `DIR` where you store 3 files:

  - `DIR/certificate.crt` which contains the certificate
  - `DIR/certificate.key` which contains the secret key for your webservice (without passphrase)
  - `DIR/certificate.bundle` which contains the CA-Bundle.  On how to prepare the bundle, see below.
- Now run the script: `./check DIR/certificate` (this assumes that the script is named `check` in the current directory)
- There is a very unlikely case that the script outputs `CA-Bundle is not needed`.  This means, that you (read: `/etc/ssl/certs/`) already trusts the signing certificate.  But this is highly unlikely in the WWW.
- For this test port 4433 must be unused on your workstation.  And better only run this in a secure environment, as it opens port 4433 shortly to the public, which might see foreign connects in a hostile environment.

**How to create the `certificate.bundle` file?**

In the WWW the trust chain usually looks like this:

- trusted certificate from `/etc/ssl/certs`
- unknown intermediate certificate(s), possibly cross signed by another CA
- your certificate (`certificate.crt`)

Now, the evaluation takes place from bottom to top, this means, first, your certificate is read, then the unknown intermediate certificate is needed, then perhaps the cross-signing-certificate and then `/etc/ssl/certs` is consulted to find the proper trusted certificate.

The ca-bundle must be made up in excactly the right processing order, this means, the first needed certificate (the intermediate certificate which signs your certificate) comes first in the bundle.  Then the cross-signing-cert is needed.

Usually your CA (the authority who signed your certificate) will provide such a proper ca-bundle-file already.  If not, you need to pick all the needed intermediate certificates and `cat` them together into a single file (on Unix).  On Windows you can just open a text editor (like `notepad.exe`) and paste the certificates into the file, the first needed on top and following the others.

There is another thing.  The files need to be in PEM format.  Some CAs issue DER (a binary) format.  PEM is easy to spot:  It is ASCII readable.  For mor on how to convert something into PEM, see [How to convert .crt to .pem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4691699/490291) and follow the yellow brick road.

Example:

You have:

- `intermediate2.crt` the intermediate cert which signed your `certificate.crt`
- `intermediate1.crt` another intermediate cert, which singed `intermediate2.crt`
- `crossigned.crt` which is a cross signing certificate from another CA, which signed `intermediate1.crt`
- `crossintermediate.crt` which is another intermediate from the other CA which signed `crossigned.crt` (you probably will never ever see such a thing)

Then the proper `cat` would look like this:

```
cat intermediate2.crt intermediate1.crt crossigned.crt crossintermediate.crt > certificate.bundle
```

And how can you find out which files are needed or not and in which sequence?

Well, experiment, until the `check` tells you everything is OK.  It is like a computer puzzle game to solve the riddle.  Every.  Single.  Time.  Even for pros.  But you will get better each time you need to do this.  So you are definitively not alone with all that pain.  It's SSL, ya' know?  SSL is probably one of the worst designs I ever saw in over 30 years of professional system administration.  Ever wondered why crypto has not become mainstream in the last 30 years?  That's why.  'nuff said.

Comment: To the downvoter:  Please explain what is wrong with my answer.  Thanks.

Comment: I am one of the downvoters. What triggered the downvote is this : "And how can you find out which files are needed or not and in which sequence?

Well, experiment, until the check tells you everything is OK". I don't think SSL is a special case. Problems like this should have a deterministic solution.

Comment: @ychaouche Thanks!  Like you I like desterministic things.  The question was, "What is wrong" and how to do it with "openssl verify".  As we are on stackoverflow, I explained that, followed by a programmatic (thus deterministic) yes/no answer.  You can even use it to automate checks for the new Bundle before installing it into production.  This fully answers the question.  What you dislike is that I told about the frustration on "How to create a proper bundle?".  As I think there cannot be a short deterministic answer for that, answering this would be offtopic in the context here.

Comment: "As Priyadi mentioned, openssl -verify stops at the first self signed certificate, hence you do not really verify the chain, as often the intermediate cert is self-signed." Obviously intermediate certificates are never self signed (if they were they'd be root certificates). And the whole point of verification is to check that you have included all the certificates in the chain all the way to a trusted root certificate. This is precisely what the openssl verify does. However, openssl tends to be rather conservative with its trusting policies...

Comment: ...this causes some confusion at times, when browsers for instance may  trust some intermediate CAs directly meaning that things may work just fine without the full chain in real life, but openssl verify will fail.

Comment: "often the intermediate cert is self-signed". This is wrong, and terminology confusions like this make it hard for newcomers to understand a topic that actually is rather simple when explained in the right way. From RFC 5280: "[...] CA certificates may be further divided into three classes: cross-certificates, self-issued certificates, and self-signed certificates.  Cross-certificates are CA certificates in which the issuer and subject are different    entities. Cross-certificates describe a trust relationship between the two CAs. [...]".

Comment: The "intermediate CA certificate" is, using the RFC 5280 terminology, actually a cross-certificate. It can never be a self-signed certificate. Those two are mutually exclusive. Ref: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280

Comment: This is a bad answer. Instead what OP could have done: verify that the chain doesn't work between the CA and the user cert if the intermediate is not included with the option `-untrusted`.

Comment: Another downvote: there is already enough confusion while explaining SSL certificates, their validity and how chains come in to play, but to have a blantly wrong "the intermediate cert is self-signed" statement near the beginning of the answer is just misleading.

Comment: This answer does not use `openssl verify`, so it does not answer the question.

Answer (score 12):

**1.** If you only want to verify that **issuer** of `UserCert.pem` **is actually** `Intermediate.pem` do the following (example uses: `OpenSSL 1.1.1`):

```
openssl verify -no-CAfile -no-CApath -partial_chain -trusted Intermediate.pem UserCert.pem
```

and you will get:

```
UserCert.pem: OK
```

or

```
UserCert.pem: verification failed
```

**2.** Same thing to verify that the issuer of `Intermediate.pem` is `RootCert.pem`

```
openssl verify -no-CAfile -no-CApath -partial_chain -trusted RootCert.pem Intermediate.pem
```

If both of the above verifications succeed then the certificate chain is verified.

Comment: is there any equivalent command for ```openssl verify -no-CAfile -no-CApath -partial_chain -trusted Intermediate.pem UserCert.pem``` in Python 3.7?

Comment: That's GOLD, Jerry, GOLD!!!

Comment: Be careful with this one, because if you have the same cert in `Intermediate.pem` and in `UserCert.pem`, it would tell you OK even when said cert is not self-signed, because you pass it as "trusted"

Answer (score 7):

I've had to do a verification of a letsencrypt certificate and I did it like this:

1. Download the root-cert and the intermediate-cert from the [letsencrypt chain of trust](https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/).
2. Issue this command:

   ```
   $ openssl verify -CAfile letsencrypt-root-cert/isrgrootx1.pem.txt -untrusted letsencrypt-intermediate-cert/letsencryptauthorityx3.pem.txt /etc/letsencrypt/live/sitename.tld/cert.pem 
   /etc/letsencrypt/live/sitename.tld/cert.pem: OK
   ```

Comment: Well, seems that John didn't like it that I said thank you. I insist on the "Thank You" tough, so here's the deleted text: Hope it helps you for your letsencrypt certs. Thanks for Priyadi, your solution helped me finding this command. Please make sure to upvote his solution.

Comment: skipping intermediate validation by suggesting `-untrusted` make this answer harmful for the purposes of "validation"

Comment: @Stof `-untrusted` does not skip anything, it simply states that its an untrusted certificate (intermediate) that needs to be validated also.
from openssl website `-untrusted file
A file of additional untrusted certificates (intermediate issuer CAs) used to construct a certificate chain from the subject certificate to a trust-anchor. The file should contain one or more certificates in PEM format. This option can be specified more than once to include untrusted certificates from multiple files.`

Comment: @maciejW you are trying to make a distinction here, which means you imply a correction to me saying 'intermediates are not validated using -untrusted' right? To be clear, you derive that they are validated? your quote only proves my point, not yours. Intermediates are provided to build a chain, but they are treated as untrusted and ignored for the purpose of validating the chain (i.e. assert the trust anchor regardless of intermeiate certificate trust)

Answer (score 5):

`openssl verify` doesn't handle certificate chains the way SSL clients do. You can replicate what they do with a three step process:

```
(cat cert.pem chain.pem | diff -q fullchain.pem -) && \
openssl verify chain.pem && \
openssl verify -CAfile chain.pem cert.pem
```

This will confirm that `fullchain.pem` == `cert.pem` + `chain.pem` and that it is legitimate according to the CAs installed on your system (usually in `/etc/ssl/certs` from your `ca-certificates` package).

---

If you are trying to validate a letsencrypt/ACME, be aware that letsencrypt gives you four files per domain:

- `cert.pem`
- `chain.pem`
- `fullchain.pem`
- `privkey.pem`

Of these, your cert pair is (`fullchain.pem`, `privkey.pem`), **not** (`cert.pem`, `privkey.pem`) nor (`chain.pem`, `privkey.pem`).

For example, in nginx.conf, you would put:

```
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/domain.example.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/domain.example.com/privkey.pem;
```

Comment: There is an open bug about this in `openssl`: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/14675

Answer (score 4):

After breaking an entire day on the exact same issue , with no prior knowledge on SSL certificates, i downloaded the [CERTivity Keystores Manager](http://www.edulib.com/products/keystores-manager/overview/) and imported my keystore to it, and got a clear-cut visualisation of the certificate chain.

Screenshot :

[image]

Comment: Doesn’t try to answer question which is about how to use `openssl verify`.

Comment: yes but this kind of tool can give you the needed visualization of that kind of things if you do not understand the cryptic information of openssl command line tools :) So here's my upvote, there might be some online stuff that do that as well.

Comment: if all you want is to see the chain and the subject/issuer for each you can run `openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl -certfile /path/to/file | openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -noout`

Answer (score 1):

If you have e.g. `cachain.pem` containing the whole CA chain starting with the root certificate and e.g. `mycert.pem` containing the certificate to check then

```
openssl verify -CAfile cachain.pem -untrusted cachain.pem mycert.pem
```

equivalent to (as openssl will read only the first certificate from `CAfile`)

```
openssl verify -CAfile root.pem -untrusted cachain.pem mycert.pem
```

will do the job. Some sources mention that `openssl verify` accepts several `-untrusted` options, but that didn't work for me with some version of `openssl`.

Answer (score -5):

You can easily verify a certificate chain with openssl. The fullchain will include the CA cert so you should see details about the CA and the certificate itself.

openssl x509 -in fullchain.pem -text -noout

Comment: 1) This is entirely without any kind of explanation. 2) this is an answer to a question the asker didn't ask, without any context.