# openssl: Not able to verify 3rd in the chain with self signed certifica

Tags: openssl

I'm trying achieve a chain of certificates, `root -> intermediate -> user1,user2,...` using OpenSSL, but I'm having issues to make a verification. Some references:

- [Verify a certificate chain using openssl verify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25482199/verify-a-certificate-chain-using-openssl-verify) Verification does not work, even with `-untrusted` it kicks out an error invalid CA certificate
- Verification `rootCA` to `intermediate` works fine, but not `user1` to `intermediate`.

Batch script:

```
:: Generate root certificate and self sign it
openssl genrsa -out rootCA.key 4096
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootCA.key -sha256 -days 1024 -out rootCA.crt -subj "/C=US/ST=CA/O=MyOrg, Inc./CN=root"

:: Intermediate certificate, signed with root CA
openssl genrsa -out intermediate.key 2048
openssl req -addext basicConstraints=CA:TRUE -new -sha256 -key intermediate.key -subj "/C=US/ST=CA/O=MyOrg, Inc./CN=intermediate" -out intermediate.csr
openssl x509 -req -in intermediate.csr -CA rootCA.crt -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out intermediate.crt -days 500 -sha256

:: User 1 certificate, signed by intermediate certificate
openssl genrsa -out user1.key 2048
openssl req -addext basicConstraints=CA:TRUE -new -sha256 -key user1.key -subj "/C=US/ST=CA/O=MyOrg, Inc./CN=user1" -out user1.csr
openssl x509 -req -in user1.csr -CA intermediate.crt -CAkey intermediate.key -CAcreateserial -out user1.crt -days 500 -sha256

:: User 2 certificate, signed by intermediate certificate
openssl genrsa -out user2.key 2048
openssl req -addext basicConstraints=CA:TRUE -new -sha256 -key user2.key -subj "/C=US/ST=CA/O=MyOrg, Inc./CN=user2" -out user2.csr 
openssl x509 -req -in user2.csr -CA intermediate.crt -CAkey intermediate.key -CAcreateserial -out user2.crt -days 500 -sha256

:: Verify user 1 certificate trust chain w/o untrusted mode
openssl verify -verbose -CAfile rootca.crt intermediate.crt user1.crt

:: Verify user 1 certificate trust chain
echo "verify check with untrusted mode"
openssl verify -verbose -CAfile rootca.crt -untrusted intermediate.crt user1.crt
```

Running verify commands:
No untrusted parameter

```
> openssl verify -verbose -CAfile rootca.crt intermediate.crt user1.crt
C = US, ST = CA, O = "MyOrg, Inc.", CN = intermediate
error 24 at 1 depth lookup: invalid CA certificate
error user1.crt: verification failed
```

With `-untrusted` parameter

```
> openssl verify -verbose -CAfile rootca.crt -untrusted intermediate.crt user1.crt
C = US, ST = CA, O = "MyOrg, Inc.", CN = intermediate
error 24 at 1 depth lookup: invalid CA certificate
error user1.crt: verification failed
```

What do I need to do, to verify if `rootca.crt` is really a root certificate for the `user1.crt`?

Script followed to generate certificates: https://gist.github.com/fntlnz/cf14feb5a46b2eda428e000157447309

Comment: Do `openssl x509 -in intermediate.crt -text` and observe that it does not have the BasicConstraints extension. Then search the dozens of existing Qs for 'openssl created cert missing extensions' here (though now offtopic) and on serverfault and security.SX to see the _working_ ways to add it. After you fix the intermediate, it usually isn't desirable to put ca:TRUE in a 'user' cert, but it may be desirable to put some or all of SAN AKI EKU.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @dave_thompson_085 will try asap