# Using wget on Windows with certificates

Tags: windows, certificate, wget

I am building a Windows script for which I'm using the Windows version of wget. The page I need to query is protected and requires a certificate to access. I currently have that client certificate installed on the computer. How can I use this certificate with wget in order to access the protected web page? Export it somehow from the Windows certificate manager?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the question about how to export a certificate from the Windows certificate store, or how to use a certificate file with wget, or both?

Comment: I know how to export it, so the question is how to export it properly (which format to use) and then how to use it with wget.

Comment: I'm not sure of the syntax for using a certificate with wget, but you probably need it in PEM format: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691699/how-to-convert-crt-to-pem

Comment: Yep, that's the one. Put that in an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of the syntax for using a certificate with wget, but you probably need it in PEM format:

[How to convert .crt to .pem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691699/how-to-convert-crt-to-pem)