# How to Install a Godaddy SSL Certificate on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: ssl, load-balancing, google-compute-engine

How do you transfer a Godaddy SSL certificate to the Google Cloud Platform?

I am trying to setup an HTTPS load balancer on Google Cloud. I have an SSL certificate from Godaddy, but I'm not sure how to input it into Google Cloud. Google has a form to enter a public key, a certificate chain, and a private key all in `.pem` format (see screenshot below). Godaddy provides me with three files: (1) a file called `#####.crt`, (2) a file called `gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt`, and (3) an RSA private key.

I've seen [other SO questions on converting `.crt` to `.pem`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691699/how-to-convert-crt-to-pem), but I'm not sure what what to do with the `.pem` files when I have them or which of these three files go into which box in the GCE console below.

[image]

Comment: Did you try to create an SslCertificate resource using gcloud compute? you can find instructions here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/ssl-certificates#createresource

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This happened to me, good to know I'm not alone!

Plain and simple answer: Godaddy will give you a certificate file and a bundle file. They all come already on PEM format (as long as it says BEGIN CERTIFICATE you know it's PEM).

Copy and paste the contents of the #####.crt file on the "Public key certificate" field, it should display the correct information on the right side of the field.

Copy and paste the contents of the certificate bundle on the "Certificate chain". This file usually has 3 certificates on it.

Finally, copy and paste the contents of your private key on the last field.

Double check that your certificate is working correctly on both desktop and mobile. If it works on desktop but not mobile try again, it means you made a mistake filling the "Certificate chain" field.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK you dont need to convert the file to PEM, quite sure it is already a PEM file, to be sure do `file gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt` or `file #####.crt` the output should be something like `PEM certificate`, you copy you private key into the "Private Key", you take .crt file and copy to the "Public key Certificate" once you do this some information will appear on the right side of these box, in my case, I copied the same .crt file on the "Certificate Chain".