# AWS set https SSL on Load Balancer Listener

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, amazon-elb

I have an `AWS ELB` on `http` and it works fine.

Now I want to add `https` listener and `AWS` requires an `SSL`:

[image]

I have `SSL` certificate in my server and I dont know where is the Private Key\Public Key Certificate their.

I have read on other `StackOverFlow` questions about it and I saw that you should use `Openssl` to convert the Certificate to `PEM` but I can't understand where is the Private Key\Public Key Certificate their which I should convert to `PEM`.

Could you please help me understand how to get those `PEMs` from my server's certificate?

Comment: Are you hosting in US-East-1? If so AWS has this built in for free! https://medium.com/@arcdigital/enabling-ssl-via-aws-certificate-manager-on-elastic-beanstalk-b953571ef4f8?source=linkShare-3b23b2f27a60-1463013160

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can follow below steps for this:-

For this you can do the following:-
1. Create SSL private key using OPENSSL.

```
sudo openssl genrsa -out your-private-key-name.pem 2048
```

2. Next, create a CSR key using OPEN-SSL

```
openssl req -sha256 -new -key your-private-key-name.pem -out csr.pem
```

The system will ask for some details, like your country, city, company name etc. Fill in those details.

3. These steps will result in two *.pem* files.
4. Now, while generating your SSL certificate from your SSL provider(Godaddy), generate the SSL certificate using the csr.pem contents.
5. After verification, you will be provided with your SSL certificate (.crt) files. [Generally, two *.crt* files]
6. Now, you have to configure this configuration onto AWS server.
7. Open the form (for which you have posted the screenshot).
   a. For private key section, post the contents of *your-private-key-name.pem* 
   b. Open one of the *.crt* files with a text editor. If this has only one set of 
   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- AND -----END CERTIFICATE-----
   paste it in the *Public Key Certificate* section.
   c. If the *.crt* file has multiple sets of 
   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- AND -----END CERTIFICATE-----
   paste it in the *Certificate Chain* section.

Now, you have entered your *Private Key*, *Public Key* and *Certificate Chain* AWS should not give any error.

***NOTE***: Do not copy the contents of *.pem* and *.crt* files directly from LINUX (vi editor). Open the files in windows and then paste the contents into the AWS form.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Before you got SSL cert from godday, you have to generate CSR file first.

Then use this link to covert to .PEM file https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html

And follow here: [How to convert .crt to .pem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691699/how-to-convert-crt-to-pem)

Comment: I have a CSR and also a .crt
About this https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html - I didn't understand what to convert to .PEM file? The .crt? (it converts it to .der), could you explain it more please?

Comment: you can follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691699/how-to-convert-crt-to-pem to covert .crt file to .pem file

Comment: Thanks, now it becomes more clear for me. I have the .pem file and I pasted it to the Public Key Certificate.
Where can I get the private key?

Comment: when you created csr file, it's being created private key as well