# How do I tell if libcurl has processed my SSL files correctly

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2015, libcurl, betfair

I am trying to login to betfair via the betfair api using curl. I have already succeeded in doing this via the command line version of curl from a bash script but I now want to do this from my C++ code directly with libcurl. Sadly libcurl is not supported by betfair so there is no direct documentation - but if command line curl works then it should all be doable.

My libcurl is failing straight away during an attempt to login (which should get a "session token" as a response). I tell curl about my certificate and key with the lines:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT,"client-2048.crt");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLKEY,"client-2048.key");
```

Later on I call `curl_easy_perform(curl);` I get a response of:

```
{"loginStatus":"CERT_AUTH_REQUIRED"}
```

According to [betfair documentation](http://docs.developer.betfair.com/docs/display/1smk3cen4v3lu3yomq5qye0ni/Non-Interactive+(bot)+login) this means: "Certificate required or certificate present but could not authenticate with it"

So I guess that somehow the SSL authentication failed. As an experiment I tried deliberatly putting garbage certificate and key file names (e.g. "client-2048_XXX.crt") but saw no difference in the response from betfair or any of the curl diagnostics (set up via `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION, my_trace);` and `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);`). So I have no way of knowing for sure the libcurl has processed my cert and key files properly. Indeed I am even suspecting that perhaps it is not processing them at all - perhaps I'm missing some other option along the lines of CURLOPT_PLEASE_USE_SSL_AUTHENTICATION which is resulting in the files being ignored?

**EDIT:** So for the record, the full sequence looks like this (some text hidden):

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://identitysso.betfair.com/api/certlogin");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT,"client-2048.crt");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLKEY,"client-2048.key");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

struct curl_slist *chunk = NULL;
chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "X-Application: _HIDDEN_");
chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk,"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, chunk);

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"username=_HIDDEN_&password=_HIDDEN_");

curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

**EDIT:** I thought that perhaps I somehow compiled my libcurl without SSL. To check this I called curl_version_info, which amongst other things gives you:

```
char *ssl_version;        /* human readable string */
```

Printing this out gave the string "WinSSL" which I assume means that SSL is included.

**EDIT:** FYI, I have four "client-2048" files, a .crt, .pem, .key and .csr. They all sit on the same directory as my exe file. I also print out the current working directory (as reported by _getcwd()) at run time just do double check that my exe is running from the right location.

**EDIT:** Here is my working login.sh (please excuse it's inelegance, I was hacking with cut and paste code and scarcely knew what I was doing). getlog.exe was a tiny utility I wrote to do some string manipulation on some JSON.

```
#!/bin/bash    
# uses rescript    
APP_KEY=_HIDDEN_
#SESSION_TOKEN=$2

HOST=https://api.betfair.com/exchange/betting
AUTHURL=https://identitysso.betfair.com/api/certlogin
CURL=curl    

function bflogin()
{
    echo "bflogin()"

    OUT=$($CURL -s -k --cert client-2048.crt --key client-2048.key --data "username=_HIDDEN_&password=_HIDDEN_" -H "X-Application: $APP_KEY" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" $AUTHURL)
    echo $OUT
    SESSION_TOKEN=$(echo $OUT | getlog.exe)
    echo
    echo "Here -> "$SESSION_TOKEN
    echo $SESSION_TOKEN > st.txt
}
```

Comment: That looks like some kind of API response to a request, not something you would get because of SSL problems. What are you trying to do? What request are you making? To what?

Comment: I'm just trying to login. - Question edited.

Comment: cert_auth_required implies that both client certificates need to be installed and a ca cert store to validate the servers identity.

Comment: @Chris Becke: A "ca cert store"? Is that a file like "client-2048.something"? pem? csr? So are you saying I need something like curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HERE_IS_THE_CA_STORE,"castorefilename"); ?

Comment: I've never used curl, but yes, I would imagine for client authenticated comms you need to initialize both the client cert to use and either the cert, or a cert store to authenticate the server.

Comment: When you were with curl directly, was that on the same (windows?) machine? You mention bash so it sounds like a different machine. Also would be helpful if you could include the curl CLI command that actually did work

Comment: Yes, same windows machine - I had installed "winbash".

Answer (score 1):

Double check the paths to you crt and key files.

Also, since you haven't specified a key encoding type, PEM is the default. You can change the encoding type with the CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE option, or try [converting your keys to PEM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691699/how-to-convert-crt-to-pem).

Comment: See edit to original post... What string should I pass as my "type" in my call to curl_easy_setopt(CURL *handle, CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE, char *type)?