# Debian SSL/TLS over corporate company proxy with own CA

Tags: linux, proxy, ssl-certificate, ca

been trying for quite some time to get this working.

The system is behind a corporate proxy which has its own CA certificates. I'm no pro at SSL/TLS stuff, so my knowledge is quite narrow. It seems I'm pretty stuck at this point.

Assuming the proxy is: proxy.b.c:123

```
> cat /etc/profile.d/proxy.sh
export http_proxy=http://proxy.b.c:123
export https_proxy=https://proxy.b.c:123
export ftp_proxy=http://proxy.b.c:123
export no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.someother.b.c
```

Trying the following:

```
> curl http://google.com
WORKS!
> wget http://google.com
WORKS!
```

I have exported the corporate certificates from Firefox CA list [(as described here)](http://blog.jimbasilio.me/2016/05/add-root-ca-trust-to-linux/), moved them to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` and ran:

```
> update-ca-certificates
> dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
```

However:

```
> curl https://google.com
curl: (35) error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
> wget https://google.com
Resolving proxy.b.c (proxy.b.c)... 
Connecting to proxy.b.c ... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://www.google.de/?... [following]
Connecting to proxy.b.c ... connected.
ERROR: The certificate of 'www.google.de' is not trusted.
ERROR: The certificate of 'www.google.de' hasn't got a known issuer.
```

Using openssl so far has not revealed anything helpful to me

```
> openssl s_client -connect google.de:443
# This takes very long .... and finally the following appears
140081117181184:error:0200206E:system library:connect:Connection timed out:../crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:108:
140081117181184:error:2008A067:BIO routines:BIO_connect:connect error:../crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:109:
140081117181184:error:02002065:system library:connect:Network is unreachable:../crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:108:
140081117181184:error:2008A067:BIO routines:BIO_connect:connect error:../crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:109:
connect:errno=101
```

Any ideas what I could try? I'm pretty lost

Answer (score 0):

Partly I have solved it.

```
> update-ca-certificates
```

complained about

```
WARNING: *.pem does not contain a certificate or CRL: skipping
```

---

I then did the following (https://stackoverflow.com/a/7397550/7071697):

```
> openssl x509 -inform DER -in *.crt -out *.pem -text
> cp *.pem *.crt
```

effectively replacing the .crt files that served as the input to create the .pem files with the resulting .pem files. * marcates the files that update-ca-certificates complained about.

---

Now

```
> wget https://google.com
```

works!!! Hurray

---

However curl still does not:

```
> curl https://google.com
curl: (35) error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

---

```
> openssl s_client -connect google.de:443
```

still returns the same as stated in the question...