# Error "data is invalid" for Custom SSL certificate Google App Engine

Tags: python, ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, ssl-certificate

I am trying to install a custom SSL certificate for google app engine but I get this error: `"The certificate data is invalid. Please ensure that the private key and public certificate match."`
So I checked with the commands:

```
openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in concat.crt | openssl md5
openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in server.key.pem | openssl md5
```

and the output is the same.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Is the certificate in the correct PEM format for Google App Engine and have you combined the leaf certificate and the chain certificates into a single file?

Comment: There are many encodings for certificates. Google wants PEM. What format is your certificate (.crt) using? Is the certificate self-signed? Provide more details about the certificates.

Comment: I used this command to convert to pem: openssl x509 -in concat.crt -outform pem -out concat.pem
but I get the same error.
The certificates are signed. I have a CA certificate and the server pem file.

Comment: If I try to convert with this command 
openssl x509 -inform der -in concat.crt -outform pem -out concat.pem 
I get the error "unable to load certificate".

Comment: Look at the certificate with a text editor. What are each header? Edit your post with details.

Comment: There are -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- there is no header.

Comment: Those are headers. You have X509 PEM. How was the certificate and private key created?

Comment: I created with openssl a certificate with private key, I've sent the certificate to an organization who provided to return back signed with a CA certificate.
After that I concatenated the returned certificate with the CA and I have uploaded the concatenated certificate and the private key on google app engine.

Comment: Based on the PEM headers, you are using the correct format. Did you make a mistake concatenating certificates, such as the wrong ones or one that is not required? You tend to reply with non-detailed responses. Details matter. For example, I wanted to see the actual openssl commands, not a description that you used openssl.

Comment: cat etpq.pem CA.cer > concat.pem

Comment: @blob, try regenerating the certificate by copying the public key only and no extra lines or spaces are copied. Check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50935458/gcp-ssl-certificate-installation-error-the-certificate-data-is-invalid-please) as reference.