# how to set-up SSL on google app engine (custom domain name )

Tags: google-app-engine

Google just announced SSL support for custom domain but I can't understand how it can be set-up as there is no way to generate Certificate Signing Request (CSR) on GAE ?!

http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&hlrm=en&answer=2644386
 Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate a certificate with a CA and upload it. They aren't offering certificate creation as a service.

Comment: Thanks  ! It seems to work by simply generating the CSR on a linux server , concatenate the CA bundle and upload it along with the private certificate (.key file)

Comment: Hi mihai, could you please give us more details (e.g. Linux commands) on how you've been able to generate this GAE-compatible CSR, for instance for a typical wildcard SSL certificate *.yourdomain.com ? The Google doc seems to assume we're all SSL cert gurus... Thanks a lot!

Comment: @LouisLC I generated a CSR (nothing special just followed the wizz) . I've got the certificate from digicert and I ended up with : DigiCertCA.crt   TrustedRoot.crt  domain.csr       domain.key       www_mydomain_com.crt . I concatenated the stuff from digicert with the following command : cat DigiCertCA.crt TrustedRoot.crt www_epek_com.crt > bundle . then I uploaded bundle and domain.key to GAE .

Answer (score 8):

To expand on the above:

The following three steps should be sufficient to generate a private key and a self-signed certificate suitable for testing SSL on GAE on a linux box:

- openssl genrsa -out yourdomain.com.key 1024
- openssl req -new -key yourdomain.com.key -out yourdomain.com.csr
- openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in yourdomain.com.csr -signkey yourdomain.com.key -out yourdomain.com.crt

Disclaimer:  It works but I do not know what I'm doing

Comment: More recent (and lower voted) answers have better info.

Answer (score 3):

Various programs exist to create a Certificate Signing Request (CSR.) I used 'openssl' on a linux machine to generate the Key and CSR.

1) I generated an Unencrypted PEM encoded RSA private key as specified by Google's SSL for a Custom Domain (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl)

```
cd $HOME
openssl genrsa -out rsa_private_key.key 2048
```

2) Use the 'rsa_private_key.key' to generate the required Certificate Signing Request (CSR) file.

```
openssl req -new -key rsa_private_key.key -out request.csr
```

You will be asked the following questions:

```
   Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]: US
   State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]: Illinois
   Locality Name (eg, city) []: Chicago
   Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]: Chicago Company, Ltd.
   Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []: IT
   Common Name (eg, YOUR name) []: checkout.customedomain.com
   Email Address []:
```

I ignored two additional questions and everything worked fine. The 'request.csr' located on your home directory ($HOME) is the CSR file needed by the Certificate Authority provider to generate your certificate(s). Again, it doesn't have to be openssl: Many tools for various platforms are supported by providers. Just keep in mind Google's requirements.

A side note regarding Custom Domains:

Make sure your CUSTOM DOMAIN includes a subdomain or 'Full Qualified Domain Name.' The 'www.' is considered a subdomain and it's ALWAYS required for ssl in Google Appengine (10/2014.) So in my example if I wanted SSL at customedomain.com I would add 'www.customedomain.com' You can re-direct your naked domain to your Full Qualified Domain Name.

Google Appengine DOES NOT provide SSL support for naked domains like: https://customedomain.com

Answer (score 2):

This is reposted from my answer at: 
[How to get .pem file from .key and .crt files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991758/how-to-get-an-openssl-pem-file-from-key-and-crt-files/31905897#31905897)

I was trying to go from godaddy to app engine. What did the trick was using this line in the terminal (mac) to generate the the key and csr:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout name.unencrypted.priv.key -out name.csr
```

Exactly as is, but replacing name with my domain name (not that it really even mattered)

Also, what follows that is a bunch of questions and I answered all the questions pertaining to common name / organization as www.name.com , and I skipped the pass code and company name by just pressing enter

Then I opened the .csr file, copied it, pasted it in go daddy's csr form, waited for godaddy to approve it, then downloaded it, unzipped it, navigated to the unzipped folder in the terminal and entered:

cat otherfilegodaddygivesyou.crt gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt > name.crt

Then I used these instructions from the post Trouble with Google Apps Custom Domain SSL, which were:

```
openssl rsa -in privateKey.key -text > private.pem
openssl x509 -inform PEM -in www_mydomain_com.crt > public.pem
```

exactly as is, except instead of privateKey.key I used name.unencrypted.priv.key, and instead of www_mydomain_com.crt, I used name.crt

Then I uploaded the public.pem to the admin console for the "PEM encoded X.509 certificate",

and uploaded the private.pem for the "Unencrypted PEM encoded RSA private key"..

.. And that finally worked.

Comment: For whatever reason to get Android to recognize the cert, I had to individually PEM encode the files from godaddy and THEN concat them. The final file had two "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" statements. 

After doing that, https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html when from grade B to grade A and after closing and after a bit, the error went away on Chrome.

Comment: it worked thanks man :) i am using google app engine and this private Rsa key had issue i used below code from stackoverflow this also worked me :)

Your private PEM file has this line:

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

Delete everything above this line and it will work.