# Trouble with Google Apps Custom Domain SSL

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, ssl-certificate, google-apps

I'm currently inside the 30-day free trial for Google Apps for business (billing set up, so will start non-free trial soon). I'm attempting to set up SSL for a custom domain for a Google App Engine app, but am a bit of a noob at this stuff and the files I've accumulated aren't accepted by the Apps submission form.

I went through the following process:

`openssl req -out CSR.csr -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout privateKey.key`

After filling in the cert. request information (with name www.mydomain.com), I had the two files CSR.csr and privateKey.key.

I used an SSL provider CheapSSLs.com to provide me with a certificate off this CSR.csr, and they've responded with a cert `www_mydomain_com.crt`.

However, on going through Google Apps Dashboard -> Security -> SSL for Custom Domains and uploading `www_mydomain_com.crt` and `privateKey.key` I'm given the error:

**Both the private key and SSL certificate should be in unencrypted PEM format.**

Any help? As far as I can tell, they *are* in that format: the private Key looks like:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEv...
...
...CftTU=
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

and the .crt file looks like:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
MIIFy...
...
...WJjk= 
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This was answered by a friendly member of the community and then immediately deleted (not sure why...) but not before I spotted his answer and used it, to great effect :)

```
openssl rsa -in privateKey.key -text > private.pem
openssl x509 -inform PEM -in www_mydomain_com.crt > public.pem
```

The above two commands produce `private.pem` and `public.pem`, which are accepted fine by Google Apps dashboard.

Thank you!

Comment: Update: you need to use @Christian's way for the private key to work

Answer (score 23):

For me, it was because my private.key was in the wrong format.

If your key starts with `---BEGIN PRIVATE KEY---` then you need to convert it to an RSA key.

```
openssl rsa -in private.key -out private_rsa.key
```

Then you should see `---BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY---` at the beginning of the `private_rsa.key` which you use with GAE.

Comment: That fixed it for me after trying the others. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Generate a new 2048-bit RSA key:

```
openssl genrsa -out myServer.key 2048
```

Convert an existing key to RSA:

```
openssl rsa -in myServer.key -out myServer-rsa.key
```