# App Engine: The private key you've selected does not appear to be valid

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl

I'm trying to add a new SSL certificate to my Google App Engine account, but after following all the steps in [the manual](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/using-custom-domains-and-ssl#obtaining_a_certificate) I kept getting this error uploading the Unencrypted PEM encoded RSA private key:

> The private key you've selected does not appear to be valid.

Anyone have experienced this issue?

Comment: Is it self generated key? Or have you got it from a trusted center?

Comment: From a trusted center (comodo)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You get this error after you paste in the certificate from comodo but before you paste in the private key and hit save? Or do you get this error after pasting in both and hitting save?
Are you sure the private key you are pasting in was the same one used to generate the CSR?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I had the same problem last week.  Google's instructions are lacking...

Your PEM file has this line:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Delete everything above this line and it will work.

Comment: If your key just says ---BEGIN PRIVATE KEY--- then you need to convert it. Run `openssl rsa -in server.key -out server_rsa.key`

Comment: @Christian and everyone. This is kinda weird, but I actually did the following

In my case, I thought the key was already in RSA, and it only needed the RSA on the delimiter, i.e.
doing a `openssl rsa -in keyfilename.key -check  -text` printed out in the middle of it:
RSA key ok
writing RSA key

So, I just added the RSA to the delimiter.. and it worked.. however! the key printed out and the original are different.. it does work though.. oh well

Answer (score 10):

Google requires an RSA formatted private key, which should have the following header (note the word **RSA**):

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

If your key has just: `---BEGIN PRIVATE KEY---` (no RSA), then you will need to convert it. You can use OpenSSL for that:

```
openssl rsa -in server.key -out server_rsa.key
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this advice! I had this headace.
Then I added the abbreviation RSA at the beginning and at the end of the key and... it worked :)!

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
[key]
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

Comment: Yes, Google App Engine's custom certificate needs the "RSA" bot be added. Thank you for saving my day!

Answer (score 3):

Ok, SSL configuration continues to be like trying to bathe a black cat in a dark room. Here's the answer that worked for me:
[Trouble with Google Apps Custom Domain SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569312/trouble-with-google-apps-custom-domain-ssl)

Comment: Truly pathetic. I can't imagine the amount of hours wasted jumping through these ridiculous configuration hoops. Every time I need to cartwheel around the room for 2 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I generated my certificates with certbot version 2.6, and had the following issues:

1. Certbot generates elliptical curve certificates by default. Google expects RSA certifcates, so add `--key-type rsa` to your certbot command.
2. Certbot private key files have to be converted with `openssl rsa -in /etc/certbot/live/somedir/privkey.pem -out /etc/certbot/live/somedir/privkey.rsa.pem`

Good luck!