# Setup SSL from COMODO for Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl

How do I setup SSL from COMODO for Google App Engine?

Originally I have used the certificate with other servers from Rackspace down to EC2 now I have migrated the domain for the certificate to GAE.

From the previous server I generated these files with openssh where these files were used for the creation of COMODO certificate:

1. mydomain.csr
2. mydomain.key

Then after registration with Namecheap.com for COMODO certificate, I got

1. www_mydomain_com.ca-bundle
2. www_mydomain_com.crt

What can I do to allow https access for my custom domain in Google App Engine?

Comment: Here are the docs https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/using-custom-domains-and-ssl?hl=en

Comment: Yes I did that but getting "The private key you've selected does not appear to be valid." however the same sets of keys worked with my Ubuntu server before (on EC2)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To fix this I had to

```
openssl rsa -in mydomain.key -text > mydomain.key.pem
```

and do this: [App Engine: The private key you've selected does not appear to be valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32891819/app-engine-the-private-key-youve-selected-does-not-appear-to-be-valid)

That is, delete the text above the `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`

Then GAE console accepted the Unencrypted PEM file.

Comment: The `-text` argument is unnecessary, then you won't have that garbage in the file to be deleted. This also fixed my new Let's Encrypt private key for use with GAE.