# Use SSL Cert with Flask Peewee

Tags: rest, ssl, salesforce, flask, peewee

I am trying to get my Flask Peewee app to work over SSL
I purchased an SSL cert and proved it was good by installing it under Apache.

I copied the code from the docs as follows:

```
from OpenSSL import SSL
context = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv3_METHOD)
context.use_privatekey_file('/etc/ssl/ssl.key/private.key')
context.use_certificate_file('/etc/ssl/ssl.crt/secure_enclude_ie.crt')
app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5001,debug=True,ssl_context=context)
```

When I run the app and check the response to a REST request, it looks fine in Firefox, but when I test it using the SSL tester at Digicert.com, it says the SSL cert is untrusted because it is not signed by a trusted authority.

Trying this in Salesforce (which is the point of the excercise), gives me a similar result.
I am assuming that I need some way to tell Flask where the root certs are on my server.
Any ideas?

Comment: I suspect that you need to include (parts of) the certificate chain as a PEM file using `use_certificate_chain_file(file)`. I sadly don't have a chance to test, but concatenating all intermediate cert PEM files (should be available from where you bought the cert) and passing the file to that function should set things up.

Comment: the seller gave me two .crt files - for the intermediate and root certs. I combined these into a PEM file using: cat AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt  COMODOSSLCA.crt > enclude.pem

Comment: but I get an error: OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('x509 certificate routines', 'X509_check_private_key', 'key values mismatch')]
Is there more to creating a PEM file?

Comment: There _may_ be, take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/991772/477878).

Comment: that's what gave me the idea to use cat to produce the pem file. I tried various combinations with the .crt files into .pem files, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Sorry, without analyzing the cert, I can't really tell much more than that :) Maybe someone with more actual Flask experience has an idea, I've only used that library with <insert big cert company name here> brand certs that worked out of the box.

Comment: Got it - I needed to put the cert I purchases, the intermediate cert and the root cert into the PEM file, as described here: https://support.commfides.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=45 thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Joachim's comment provided the clue, but I can't see how to mark his comment as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you need to include (parts of) the certificate chain as a PEM file using `use_certificate_chain_file(file)`.

Concatenating all intermediate cert PEM files (should be available from where you bought the cert) and passing the file to that function should set things up.