# Why won't zend 2 http verify my ssl cert?

Tags: php, ssl, zend-framework2

I've just started using Zend 2 and it works really well (locally) but I can't get it to pass data via https to another server.

I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to ssl certs and I think this is where the problem lies. I've got a CERT, a Private Key and a CA cert - these are being used for an ssl cert on one of our vhost domains on our server the locations are : -

```
SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/psa/var/certificates/cert-####
SSLCACertificateFile /usr/local/psa/var/certificates/cert-####
```

In every example I read they're in '/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.pem'. My question is how to I stick them together to create this .pem file that zend 2 wants? I've tried just creating a .pem file with all the -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- the hash/key -----END CERTIFICATE----- in and named it ca-bundle.pem but now Apache throws  'Unable to set verify locations' error at me, how do I get this to work ? Here is a snippet of the code I have for the adapter : -

```
$adapter = new Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Socket();
$adapter->setStreamContext(array(
'ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer' => true,
    'allow_self_signed' => false,
    'cafile' => '/usr/local/psa/var/certificates/ca-bundle.pem',
    'verify_depth' => 5,
    'CN_match' => 'https://www.mydomain.co.uk'
)
));

$client->setAdapter($adapter);
```

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 0):

First this, but I guess you already did that correctly: [How to get .pem file from .key and .crt files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991758/how-to-get-an-openssl-pem-file-from-key-and-crt-files)

The error `Unable to set verify locations` is because Apache can't find or read the key.

Solution:

1. verify the path is correct
2. make sure the pem file is readable by the www-user Apache runs with

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error when trying to install Composer.  The following command corrected the problem for me.

```
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

I had installed an SSL certificate on this server following given instructions and it worked for the https connection.  It was only when trying to install Composer that I saw the "unable to set verify locations" error.  I hope this can save others the hours of research time it cost me!