# What is the relationship between these openssl files: example.cer example.key example.pem example.crt?

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate, pem

I am config the ssl using [`Mechanize`](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize), according the [document](http://docs.seattlerb.org/mechanize/EXAMPLES_rdoc.html) I need to set the

```
agent.cert = 'example.cer'
agent.key='example.cer'
```

but how can I get these two file? I also find that ssl file has a lot of types, such as `.cer` `.pem` `.crt` `.key`, what is the relationship between them?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from PEM files, which are your digital certificates written in form encoded in only basic ASCII characters, they can be easily copy&pasted, e-mailed, printed. More about them:

- [Working with PEM files](http://how2ssl.com/articles/working_with_pem_files/)
- [How to get an OpenSSL .pem file from .key and .crt files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991758/how-to-get-an-openssl-pem-file-from-key-and-crt-files)

The file with `.crt` extension is PEM or DER, which is just binary encoded certificate. This extension is recognized by Windows, while PEM or DER aren't.

The file with `.key` extension is just your private key. It's stored in separate file. Format not standardized.

You will find more information about all these formats in the answer on serverfault: [What is a PEM file and how does it differ from other OpenSSL generated key file formats?](https://serverfault.com/questions/9708/what-is-a-pem-file-and-how-does-it-differ-from-other-openssl-generated-key-file)