# How to write this script in RoR

Tags: bash, ruby-on-rails-4, curl

How to write this code by ruby on rails?

```
curl -k --cert path/cert.cer --key path/private.key -F "file=path/pkcs7.file" https://server.com/test > resp.txt
```

**UPDATE:**
I'am used gem curb, my solution:

```
http = Curl.post("https://server.com/test", signed_data) do|http|
  http.cert = "path/included_key.pem" # in linux: cat path/cert.cer path/private.key > path/included_key.pem, more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991758/how-to-get-an-openssl-pem-file-from-key-and-crt-files
  http.certpassword = '198512' # is optional
  http.headers["Content-Type"] = 'application/pkcs7-mime' # is optional, needs for me
  http.ssl_verify_peer = false # is equal -k flag in curl
end
Rails.logger.info http.body_str
```

Comment: rails is a framework. you cant code that in rails. you might code that in ruby using the net:http library

Comment: I wrote the script, you can see it in the topic

Comment: good. so whats your question now? how to save the result in a text file ?

Comment: I wanted to write a script that simply receives data. My question is closed. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Solution

```
http = Curl.post("https://server.com/test", signed_data) do|http|
  http.cert = "path/included_key.pem" # in linux: cat path/cert.cer path/private.key > path/included_key.pem, more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991758/how-to-get-an-openssl-pem-file-from-key-and-crt-files
  http.certpassword = '198512' # is optional
  http.headers["Content-Type"] = 'application/pkcs7-mime' # is optional, needs for me
  http.ssl_verify_peer = false # is equal -k flag in curl
end
Rails.logger.info http.body_str
```

Comment: glad u figured it out