# What Do We Use for Android N Network Security Configuration for a Self-Signed Certificate?

Tags: android, ssl, android-7.0-nougat

I am trying to test out all aspects of the network security configuration capability of the N Developer Preview. I have most of it working, but I am stumped by the self-signed certificate scenario.

According to [the docs](http://developer.android.com/preview/features/security-config.html#CustomTrust), Android N should be happy with a PEM or DER file, as it is for other certificate validation scenarios. However, I do not work with self-signed certificates much, and my attempts to get this working keep running into certificate path validation exceptions.

For testing, I am using `thin` as the server, running on my development machine, reachable by an N emulator. The self-signed certificate works for browsers on my development machine, and if I switch to running `thin` sans SSL, apps can reach the server just fine. So, it's not a connectivity issue.

I created the self-signed certificate using the instructions on [this site](https://serversforhackers.com/self-signed-ssl-certificates):

```
sudo openssl genrsa -out "/etc/[webserver]/ssl/example.key" 2048
sudo openssl req -new -key "/etc/[webserver]/ssl/example.key" \
                 -out "/etc/[webserver]/ssl/example.csr"
sudo openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in "/etc/[webserver]/ssl/example.csr" \
                  -signkey "/etc/[webserver]/ssl/example.key"  \
                  -out "/etc/[webserver]/ssl/example.crt"
```

According to [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991758/how-to-get-an-openssl-pem-file-from-key-and-crt-files), the `example.crt` file is a PEM file. Elsewhere, I see instructions for creating [a "combined PEM" file](https://gist.github.com/mtigas/952344). However, I tried both of these, with no luck.

In terms of the network security configuration stuff, I have tried both `<domain-config>` and `<debug-overrides>`. The latter looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<network-security-config>
  <debug-overrides>
    <trust-anchors>
      <certificates src="@raw/selfsigned"/>
    </trust-anchors>
  </debug-overrides>
</network-security-config>
```

But, I get the validation error in either case.

What exactly should we be putting in as a PEM or DER file, as a raw resource, that makes this work?

Comment: Have you added `android:debuggable = true` ?

Comment: @PrerakSola: I am testing from a series of product flavors, but I am always using `debug` as the build type.

Comment: I tried this out by generating a self signed certificate as you outlined and it worked. I copied the example.crt file, put it in the raw resource folder, and removed the extension. I think the only big difference is I am running Tomcat locally as the web server. One thing to double check is that you added the meta-data element to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. The cert worked with any of `<base-config>`, `<domain-config>`, or `<debug-overrides>` in the xml file.

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan: Out of curiosity, did you try it on N Developer Preview 2 (NDP2) or NDP1? When I posted this, I was testing on NDP1. Now, with a fresh emulator with NDP2, it is working with the plain CRT file (not the "combined PEM" one). The file extension does not seem to matter -- it works with or without, which makes sense, given that it's a raw resource. Thanks for the kick in the right direction!

Comment: I am showing revision 2 which I assume means I'm using NDP2 so maybe there was an issue in the original preview. I'm not sure how to go back and try testing using NDP1.

Comment: OK, I am going to assume it was actually a bug and is fixed now. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Where did you obtain **example.crt** from?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky: It is the output of the `openssl` command pipeline shown in the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This appears to be working on N Developer Preview 2, using the `example.crt` generated by the `openssl` scripts shown in the question. For the moment, I am going to assume that there was a change in N Developer Preview 2 compared to N Developer Preview 1 that accounts for the change.