# How to configure CAs for Debugging Android

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate

For debugging my app that connects over HTTPS, I want to connect to a local development server, which does not have the SSL certificate for my production server.

I read that I can do this without any modification to my app's code by specifying debug-only CAs, which are trusted only when android:debuggable is true.

This seems to be working, however, the suggested app code example in the following link is not clear.  https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html#TrustingDebugCa

Code example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <debug-overrides>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/debug_cas"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </debug-overrides>
</network-security-config>
```

This code example is not clear, because I do not know what debug_cas is. Can someone help me with this?

I was able to get this working using the following code, however, I am not sure if setting the src="user" is secure.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
    <debug-overrides>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="user" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </debug-overrides>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36552316/115145

Comment: @CommonsWare this is more clear, thanks! I understand what to do.