# How to use certificate and private key in my TCP server?

Tags: java, ssl, netty, tcpserver

I built a TCP server (using Netty). If I pass an SSLContext during the server initialization then the server will start encrypting the messages between it and the clients.

I have a certificate and private key (of type DER). How can I create an SSLContext from those?

Comment: What is the significance of the OpenSSL tag? Please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: I put it there because I understood for other posts that I might need to generate  jks file from my certificate and that I think I'd need openssh to generate it

Comment: You do, and that's why this is indeed a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991758/how-to-get-an-openssl-pem-file-from-key-and-crt-files?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: So there isn't a way to programmatically generate a jks file without calling openssh commands?