# Heroku says all free apps are served through https. How can I get the .pem file?

Tags: ssl, heroku, alexa-skills-kit

I have found multiple mentions of piggyback-SSL on the Internet, which means all your Heroku applications on `*.herokuapp.com` can be accessible with HTTPS.

However, I'm trying to write an Alexa [skill](https://developer.amazon.com/alexa-skills-kit), and to do that, I need the contents of the `.pem` file; i have no idea how piggyback-SSL works, and how I can get the contents of the `.pem` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unlikely you'd be able to get your hands on this as the `.pem` file would include the private key which Heroku will be keeping secret.

You'll need to get your own SSL certificate and install it on your application. When you have your own SSL certificate and private key, you can generate your own pem file.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl

[How to get .pem file from .key and .crt files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991758/how-to-get-pem-file-from-key-and-crt-files)