# What is the difference between a personal pem file and a standard pem file?

Tags: ios, certificate

[image]

Notice in the picture the icon image for certs has either Standard or Personal written on it.  What is the difference? The most recent time I'm working on it, I produced only icons with "Personal" on them.  I don't know why.  What is the difference? How are both produced?

Answer (score 1):

I would say it because your.p12 files include your private key. And the.cer files only contain the certificate.

Pem is a container format. It can include just the public certificate, or public key, private key, and root certificates.

p12 is commonly used to bundle a private key with a certificate. "Making it personal".

.cer is just the certificate

Check this answer for how to create [pem files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991758/how-to-get-pem-file-from-key-and-crt-files)