# MongoDB connecting over SSL: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, mongodb, database-administration

**Overview:** I have an application server running PHP 7, connecting to a separate database server running MongoDB 3.6.x using the MongoDB PHP userland library. I have firewall rules preventing access to the MongoDB server from all sources except the local and private interfaces (i.e. disallowing public IP access).

Connections via PHP look something like this:

```
$context_information = array(
    "ssl" => array(
        "allow_self_signed" => false,
        "verify_peer"       => true,
        "verify_peer_name"  => true,
        "verify_expiry"     => true,
        "cafile"            => "/path/to/ca_bundle"
));

$context = stream_context_create($context_information);
$connection = new MongoDB\Client(
    $host,
    array('ssl'=>true),
    array('context'=> $context)
);
```

My MongoDB configuration looks something like this:

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,10.138.196.241
  ssl:
    mode: requireSSL
    PEMKeyFile: /path/to/my_ca_signed_cert
    CAFile: /path/to/my_ca_bundle
```

`my_ca_signed_cert` is a `.pem` file generated using my openssl-generated RSA private key, as well as the CA-provided `.crt` file, in the manner described in the MongoDB manual, e.g. `cat mongodb.key mongodb.crt > mongodb.pem`. `my_ca_bundle` is the `.ca-bundle` provided to me by the CA.

Additionally, the `ca_bundle` described in the PHP context is the same `.ca-bundle` file as in the MongoDB config.

**Problem:** I continue to receive the following error:

> [23-Jul-2018 16:33:33 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ConnectionTimeoutException: No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [TLS handshake failed: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed calling ismaster on. . .

This issue persists even if I comment out the `CAFile` line for the MongoDB config. Also of note is that I can connect successfully when setting `allow_self_signed` to `true` if `CAFile` is commented out, but not when it's left uncommented.

Finally, when attempting to connect via the MongoDB shell, I get the following error:

> 2018-07-23T23:37:02.992+0000 E NETWORK  [thread1] SSL peer certificate validation failed: unable to get issuer certificate
>
> 2018-07-23T23:37:02.992+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: socket exception [CONNECT_ERROR] for SSL peer certificate validation failed: unable to get issuer certificate :
>
> connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
>
> @(connect):1:6
>
> exception: connect failed

**Expected Behavior:** I don't want to use client certificate authentication for connecting to the database. All I want at present is for traffic to be encrypted. This means being able to connect to the database without allowing self-signed certificates.

**Notes:**

1. I have a cert set up successfully on the application server for HTTPS connectivity. Additionally, when testing the cert referenced in this question itself, I've successfully run verification on the files using `openssl verify -CAfile /path/to/my_ca_bundle /path/to/my_ca_signed_cert`.
2. Everything in my application code works when SSL is disabled or when enabled while allowing self-signed certs.

The documentation on all of this is incredibly vague on a number of points, so I'm not sure where my configuration is going wrong. What should I be looking into to resolve this problem?

Comment: Is your .crt and .key files binary or text? Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/991772/2235381

Comment: @lojza They're text files, in PEM format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to take another crack at this problem and finally found a solution.

First, I needed to move my `/path/to/my_ca_bundle` to `/usr/share/ca-certificates/my_project/my_ca_bundle`.

Second, I needed to update `/etc/ca-certificates.conf` with the line `my_project/my_ca_bundle`.

Third, I needed to run `sudo update-ca-certificates`.

Finally, I needed to remove the `ssl.cafile` option from my PHP stream context (I can't seem to get it to work with this line in place).

The `CAFile` option in `/etc/mongod.conf` is unnecessary as well, and is problematic unless it uses the `allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates: true` line noted in the other answer.

That was a mess, but everything works now!

Comment: awesome finding!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try adding the option `allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates` to ssl configuration. Your connection is encrypted but ignoring the certificate authentication.

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,10.138.196.241
  ssl:
    mode: requireSSL
    PEMKeyFile: /path/to/my_ca_signed_cert
    CAFile: /path/to/my_ca_bundle
    allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates: true
```

More info here:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.ssl.allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates

Comment: I'd completely forgotten about that option! Even so, after adding it in, I still have the same problem. Even with `CAFile` commented out, the problem persists. I'll definitely be keeping it in mind, however.