# Setting up an SSL cert with Google Cloud Load Balancer

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-load-balancer

I'm trying to setup google cloud load balancer for SSL using a certificate (PositiveSSL) that I generated via a certificate authority.

Via the google cloud shell, here is how I generated the key:

```
openssl genrsa -out my-key.key 2048
```

And here is how I generated the CSR (certificate signing request):

```
openssl req -new -key my-key.key -out my-csr.csr
```

I then used the CSR to obtain the SSL cert from the certificate authority, and I received the following two files:

1. my-crt.crt
2. my-ca-bundle.ca-bundle

All tolled, I have the following four files:

1. my-key.key
2. my-csr.csr
3. my-crt.crt
4. my-ca-bundle.ca-bundle

The image shown below is the form for creating an SSL cert in Google Cloud Load Balancer:

[image]

Can you please direct me as to what information goes where (from the files I have at my disposal). I don't have any files that are in `.pem` format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- my-crt.crt is the public key certificate
- my-key.key is the private key to your certificate
- my-ca-bundle.ca-bundle is your certificate chain

Open those files up, copy and paste the content to the form.

This is described in GCP documentation on ["Creating and Using SSL Certificates"](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates) under the section ["Creating an SSL certificate resource from existing certificate files"](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates#createresource) as per the doc

- In the Public key certificate field, click the Upload button to
  upload your .crt file or paste the entire contents of your .key file
  into the field, including the -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- and
  -----END CERTIFICATE----- that enclose the file contents.
- In the Certificate chain field, click the Upload button to upload
  your .csr file or paste the entire contents of the .csr file into the
  field, including the -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST----- and -----END
  CERTIFICATE REQUEST----- that encloses the file contents.
- In the Private key certificate field, click the Upload button to
  upload your private key, using the .key file generated previously.
  This file uses, for example, -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- and
  -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY----- to enclose the file contents.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely copy paste from the files. However, if you would like to create a .pem file then I have found [this document that describes how to create a .pem File for SSL Certificate Installations](https://support.microfocus.com/kb/doc.php?id=7013103). As per the document, the Privacy Enhanced Mail (PEM) files are concatenated certificate containers frequently used in certificate installations when multiple certificates that form a complete chain are being imported as a single file. You can think of it as a layered container of chained certificates. A .pem file is a container format that may just include the public certificate or the entire certificate chain (private key, public key, root certificates):

- Private Key
- Server Certificate (crt, puplic key) 
    (optional)Intermediate CA and/or bundles if signed by a 3rd party

How to create a self-signed PEM file:

> openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -nodes -x509 -days 3650 -keyout
>   key.pem -out cert.pem

How to create a PEM file from existing certificate files that form a chain:

1) Remove the password from the Private Key (optional) by following the steps listed below:

- Type openssl rsa -in server.key -out nopassword.key and press Enter.
- Enter the pass phrase of the Private Key.

2) Combine the private key, public certificate and any 3rd party intermediate certificate files:

> cat nopassword.key > server.pem
>   cat server.crt >> server.pem

Repeat this step as needed for third-party certificate chain files, bundles, etc:

> cat intermediate.crt >> server.pem

Additionally, I have found another server fault article on [How to create a .pem File for SSL Certificate Installations.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991758/how-to-get-pem-file-from-key-and-crt-files)

Comment: Thanks for the alternative option. Seems easier to just copy and paste though.