# Convert CSR.txt certificate into .pem

Tags: c#, asp.net, certificate, csr

I have a CSR.txt certificate with the private key which is provided by the client and I want to convert that CSR file into .pem format.

I`m trying to convert the .csr file to .pem through OpenSSL.

Can anyone help me out with this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get .pem file from .key and .crt files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991758/how-to-get-pem-file-from-key-and-crt-files)

Comment: Can you give an example of a `CSR.txt certificate`?  I'm not at all sure what that means.

Comment: -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
MIIE4TCCAskCAQAwgZsxCzAJBgNVBAYTAkRPMR0wGwYDVQQD......
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJQwIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCCS0wggkpAgEAAoICAQDcCtWvZMvfni7y.......
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

Comment: CSR.txt file containing private key and certificate as per above sample

Comment: This is wired, CSR generally will not contain PRIVATE KEY, from where you are getting such files?

Comment: Is there any way to convert .csr to .pem format?

Comment: @BharatVasant, ya it's weird but they provided this text file for testing environment.

Comment: Just copy `
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST----- MIIE4TCCAskCAQAwgZsxCzAJBgNVBAYTAkRPMR0wGwYDVQQD...... -----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----` and save it with the extension `.pem` and you are done

Comment: .pem file created as above will not have Private Key and may not be useful for signing or encryption.