# How to download Cpanel auto-generated SSL as (key.pem and cert.pem)

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, cpanel

I want to download Cpanel auto-generated SSL as key.pem and cert.pem, I don't find any download link in Cpanel, Any suggestion?

I have tried copying the certificate text in a text file and using it, but didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution here:
[How to get .pem file from .key and .crt files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991758/how-to-get-pem-file-from-key-and-crt-files)

Summary: Cpanel offers to read the certificate and its key as a text in binary and in ascii formats.
Just copy the ASCII format ( starts with --begin ) and paste it in a text file, name this file as cert.pem, and you are done.

Same goes for the key.

It worked fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, How one can manage this process if they need the .pem file for their websockets or for mobile app internal use. These certificates auto renew after 3 months on cPanel so then how to keep it updated without manual work?