# OpenSSL get Private and Public Key Function return False

Tags: php, ssl, openssl, jwt, pem

I want to encode and decode my data using Laravel [PHP-JWT package](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt#example-with-rs256-openssl). which require Private and Public Key in string format.

Therefore, I have created the `certificate.pem` by [converting .crt to .pem format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/991772/14138027) using below command

`x509 -inform DER -outform PEM -in cert.crt -out certificate.pem`

As [openssl_pkey_get_private](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-get-private.php#refsect1-function.openssl-pkey-get-private-parameters) and [openssl_pkey_get_public](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-get-public.php#refsect1-function.openssl-pkey-get-public-parameters) accept certificate in .pem format as parameter and [Return Positive Key Resources](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-get-private.php#refsect1-function.openssl-pkey-get-private-returnvalues).

> Note: **Positive Key Resouces** is `resource id='588' type='OpenSSL key'` in debugging.

```
/* Path to certificate */
$path = storage_path('test/certificate.pem'); 

/* Extract the private key from $res to $privKey */
$privKey = openssl_pkey_get_private($path);

/* Extract the public key from $res to $pubKey */
$pubKey = openssl_pkey_get_public($path);
```

> **Query 1: Returning `false` in both `$privKey` and `$pubKey`**

> **Query 2: Will [`JWT::encode`](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt#example-with-rs256-openssl) accept as a parameter these [`Key Resouces`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-get-private.php#refsect1-function.openssl-pkey-get-private-returnvalues) object which is returning from OpenSSL function?**

Is there any alternative?

**Edit 1:** I have OpenSSL enabled in phpinfo.

**Edit 2:** [openssl_error_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-error-string.php) output.

```
$path = storage_path('test/certificate.pem'); 
$private_key = openssl_pkey_get_private(file_get_contents($path)); // resource id='565' type='OpenSSL key'
$public_key = openssl_pkey_get_public(file_get_contents($path)); // false
$pubkey_error_message = openssl_error_string(); // "error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line"
```

Comment: Does the fike exist? What does https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-error-string.php output?

Comment: @MrTux. Let me check openssl_error_string output.

Comment: @MrTux, Yes file does exist.

Comment: @MrTux, It is returning `error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line` following error message.