# Yaws webserver running via HTTP but not via HTTPS

Tags: ssl, https, erlang, yaws

I have a yaws webserver. I'm trying to connect via https in local network.
When I setup my server in yaws.conf for http, as follows, all works fine when I connect via http://0.0.0.0:80/myappmod in browser

```
<server *:80>
    port = 80
    listen = 0.0.0.0
    docroot = /home/anyuser/anydir/
    auth_log = true
    appmods = </, myappmod>
</server>
```

But the following config (with ssl) does not: (I connect via https://0.0.0.0:443/myappmod)

```
<server mydomain.com>
    port = 443
    docroot = /home/anyuser/anydir/
    listen = 0.0.0.0
    dir_listings = true
    auth_log = true
    appmods = </, myappmod> 
    <ssl>  
        keyfile = /home/anyuser/private-key.pem
        certfile = /home/anyuser/cert_by_ca.pem
        depth = 0
    </ssl>
</server>
```

The certificate is officially issued by certificate authority and generally works for other webservers under "mydomain.com".
private-key format is this

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKcwggSjAgEAAoIBAQC7WBJR0YV9bq4P
...
CAy+LaJpyW/b2vQ+He7t/rg=
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

And .crt file is of this format:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGgjCCBWqgAwIBAgIIZiCEI/Q/x7gwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwgbQxCzAJBgNV
...
1CtNn+5v4lBpgzWS0ZSv5xkeskHjzXnRbjl7jzbkwUdseCZHwXc=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

When I'm trying to connect, I get **ERR_CONNECTION_RESET** in Chrome and **PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR** in firefox.
What am I doing wrong? I can't find any more infos on the config in the official yaws docs. Can someone help please?

EDIT:

`trace.log` output from `curl -v -k --trace-ascii trace.log https://0.0.0.0:443/`:

```
== Info:   Trying 0.0.0.0:443...
== Info: Connected to 0.0.0.0 (127.0.0.1) port 443 (#0)
== Info: ALPN, offering h2
== Info: ALPN, offering http/1.1
== Info: TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
=> Send SSL data, 5 bytes (0x5)
0000: .....
== Info: TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
=> Send SSL data, 512 bytes (0x200)
0000: .......w.`0V;k.z;7...}1..Y..5.;..WjO.. .4.,30.....L.......3.../.
0040: ..Y.....>.......,.0.........+./...$.(.k.#.'.g.....9.....3.....=.
0080: <.5./.....u..................................3t.........h2.http/
00c0: 1.1.........1.....*.(.........................................+.
0100: .......-.....3.&.$... ....d>..xlz#..H.V...|.R.s.k.t..r..........
0140: ................................................................
0180: ................................................................
01c0: ................................................................
== Info: OpenSSL SSL_connect: Die Verbindung wurde vom Kommunikationspartner zurückgesetzt in connection to 0.0.0.0:443 
== Info: Closing connection 0
== Info: TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, decode error (562):
=> Send SSL data, 2 bytes (0x2)
0000: .2
```

EDIT2: *Die Verbindung wurde vom Kommunikationspartner zurückgesetzt* means: **The connection was reset by the communication partner** in English.

Is the **decode error (562)** due to invalid cert-file encoding? I must admid, that I got 2 files from godaddy.com: One `.pem` and one `.crt` file. Their contents looked identically to me. Content is as posted above.(I used the .pem file in yaws.conf). The key-file I am using is the output I copied from the cert sign request on godaddy.com. (Just copied it from their Web-TextBox and pasted it into a .txt file on ubuntu).

EDIT3:

`openssl s_client -connect mydomain.com:443` (dns works for http//mydomain.de:80) gives me:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=104
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 310 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

EDIT4:

So I produced some more output. First I verified, that my certificate is ok. Therefore I made an openssl-client and server the following way:

```
openssl s_server -accept 8443 -cert /etc/mydomain.pem -key /etc/mydomain.key -CAfile /etc/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt

openssl s_client -connect localhost:8443 -cert /etc/mydomain.pem -key /etc/mydomain.key -CAfile /etc/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt -verify 8 -verify_hostname mydomain.de
```

Which results in a successful handshake:

```
... Certificate and other data I do not want to post and:

SSL handshake has read 5658 bytes and written 373 bytes
Verification: OK
Verified peername: mydomain.de

... more data
```

Then I setup one http and one http server using the following config file. I further assured .pem and .key file can be accessible by yaws with chmod +777 (I know this is bad but I just wanted to be sure). Then I started the yaws server (with root priviliges, which I know is evil too, but until I figured out how to bind to priviliged ports as non-root, I go with that just for testing)

```
logdir = /var/log/yaws
ebin_dir = /usr/local/lib/yaws-appmods/ebin
include_dir = /usr/local/lib/yaws-appmods/include
max_connections = nolimit
keepalive_maxuses = nolimit
process_options = "[]"
acceptor_pool_size = 8
trace = false
use_old_ssl = false
copy_error_log = true
log_wrap_size = 0
log_resolve_hostname = false
fail_on_bind_err = true
pick_first_virthost_on_nomatch = false
keepalive_timeout = 30000
sni = enable

<server mydomain.de>
    port = 80
    listen = 192.168.178.75
    docroot = /home/my_non_root_user/my_appmod/
    auth_log = true
    appmods = </, my_appmod>
</server>


<server mydomain.de>
    port = 443
    docroot = /home/my_non_root_user/my_appmod/
    listen = 192.168.178.75
    dir_listings = true
    auth_log = true
    appmods = </, my_appmod>    
    <ssl>  
        keyfile = /etc/mydomain.key
        certfile = /etc/mydomain.pem
        depth = 0
    </ssl>
</server>
```

I also tried providing the ca-bundle, setting higher depths, and played with some other parameters, but all to no success. I got the same error as described above. In the following yaws output, one only can see that http is working. When I try to connect via https, there is no output produced. No worker, etc. I am very new to yaws and webservers in general. I like erlang very much, and just wanted to have a small webserver for my own. No production ready, sophisticated solution. I guess I did something wrong in my config file or have just incomplete knowledge about the whole webserver concept.

```
1> =INFO REPORT==== 30-Jan-2022::21:16:55.826108 ===
Yaws: Using config file /etc/yaws/yaws.conf

=ERROR REPORT==== 30-Jan-2022::21:16:55.839289 ===
use_old_ssl in yaws.conf is no longer supported - ignoring

=INFO REPORT==== 30-Jan-2022::21:16:55.904479 ===
yaws debug:Add path "/usr/local/lib/yaws-appmods/ebin"

=INFO REPORT==== 30-Jan-2022::21:16:55.906202 ===
yaws debug:Add path "/usr/lib/yaws/examples/ebin"

=INFO REPORT==== 30-Jan-2022::21:16:55.906272 ===
yaws debug:Running with id="default" 
Running with debug checks turned on (slower server) 
Logging to directory "/var/log/yaws"

=INFO REPORT==== 30-Jan-2022::21:16:55.911016 ===
Ctlfile : /root/.yaws/yaws/default/CTL

=INFO REPORT==== 30-Jan-2022::21:16:55.911698 ===
sync call startup:start 

ENSURE SSL: {ok,[]}

=INFO REPORT==== 30-Jan-2022::21:16:56.045817 ===
Trace directory "/var/log/yaws/trace_20220130_211656" created

=INFO REPORT==== 30-Jan-2022::21:16:56.055200 ===
Yaws: Listening to 192.168.178.75:443 for <1> virtual servers:
 - https://mydomain.de under /home/my_non_root_user/my_appmod

=INFO REPORT==== 30-Jan-2022::21:16:56.055388 ===
Yaws: Listening to 192.168.178.75:80 for <1> virtual servers:
 - http://mydomain.de under /home/my_non_root_user/my_appmod

Worker: <0.194.0> 
[2022-01-30 21:17:15.987] ===== CLI -> SRV =====
New (nossl) connection from 80.*.*.*:57260                // * are manually hidden numbers for stackoverflow post

Worker: <0.200.0> 
[2022-01-30 21:17:15.987] ===== CLI -> SRV =====
New (nossl) connection from 80.*.*.*:57262                // here too

Worker: <0.200.0> 
[2022-01-30 21:17:15.994] ===== CLI -> SRV =====
GET / HTTP/1.1
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, application/xml;q=0.9, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, */*;q=0.8, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Host: mydomain.de
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36
Cookie: pvisitor=cc2529f0-abf8-4e78-80d2-85908b25f227
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,de-DE;q=0.8,de;q=0.7
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1


Worker: <0.200.0> 
[2022-01-30 21:17:15.996] ===== SRV -> CLI =====
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Yaws 2.1.0
Date: Sun, 30 Jan 2022 20:17:15 GMT
Content-Length: 46
Content-Type: text/html


Worker: <0.200.0> 
[2022-01-30 21:17:16.203] ===== CLI -> SRV =====
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, image/svg+xml, image/*, */*;q=0.8
Host: mydomain.de
Referer: http://mydomain.de/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36
Cookie: pvisitor=cc2529f0-abf8-4e78-80d2-85908b25f227
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,de-DE;q=0.8,de;q=0.7
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate


Worker: <0.200.0> 
[2022-01-30 21:17:16.203] ===== SRV -> CLI =====
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Server: Yaws 2.1.0
Date: Sun, 30 Jan 2022 20:17:16 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html
```

Comment: Perhaps running `curl -v -k --trace-ascii trace.log https://0.0.0.0:443/` and then checking `trace.log` will help identify what's going wrong. You can also run Yaws interactively from a shell command line via `yaws -i --tracetraf --tracehttp --traceout` and it will emit trace info to stdout that might also help.

Comment: @SteveVinoski: Thank you very much for your help! I posted the output of trace.log as edit to the above question, together with a guess of mine about the ocurring `decode error (562)`. I googled it but I'm not wiser now though :/

Comment: What version of Yaws are you using, and what version of Erlang/OTP? Also, are you seeing any errors or crashes logged by Yaws?

Comment: @SteveVinoski: `erlang:system_info(otp_release). = "24"` with `Yaws 2.1.0`. There is no error output from `yaws -i --tracetraf --tracehttp --traout` stdoutput is all okay. Just the normal Reports. When I do https request acutally nothing happens in yaws. No output. Yaws reports `=INFO REPORT==== 28-Jan-2022::18:33:20.991754 ===
Trace directory "/var/log/yaws/trace_20220128_183320" created` but the directory has only empty file of pattern: `'trace.\<0.*.0\.http'`in it.

Comment: @SteveVinoski: Does this output of `openssl s_client -connect mydomain.com:443` (EDIT3 above) help? There seems to be no cert at all.

Comment: I set up Yaws with a sample configuration with trace enabled as I specified earlier, then ran `openssl s_client -connect localhost:8443` against it and it showed correct certificate details. Yaws trace output showed `Worker` messages for new SSL connections and the closing of those connections. Do you see similar `Worker` trace messages? Does your `yaws.conf` file specify a  setting for `pick_first_virthost_on_nomatch` ? If not, please try setting `pick_first_virthost_on_nomatch = false` in the global section, not in a server block.

Comment: @SteveVinoski: I provided some more information (EDIT4 forward). I hope this helps understanding my problem a litte bit better. And thanks a lot for your patience btw

Comment: Interesting that you're getting a 405 status code. What does your appmod do? Can you either try running without an appmod, or try replacing your appmod with a really simple one that just returns `{status, 200}`? Also feel free to email me if it would be faster than going through these comments.

Comment: @SteveVinoski: I think the 405 is due to the favicon.ico request made by chrome which I do not handle right at the moment. I wrote you an email to your IEEE adress. Hope this is the correct one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `yaws.conf` file, your `keyfile` parameter in the `<ssl>` block refers to a file with a `.key` suffix. According to the [Erlang ssl module man page](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ssl.html#type-key_pem), that file should instead be in PEM format (i.e., a `.pem` file).

- The `ssl` man page says if you leave out the `keyfile` parameter, it defaults to the same as `certfile`, so you could try dropping `keyfile` from your `yaws.conf` file to see if that helps.
- If that doesn't work, you likely need to convert the `.key` file to a `.pem` file; [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991758/how-to-get-pem-file-from-key-and-crt-files) describes how to do it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I can accept your answer put I do not have enough reputation to give it an upvote. Hope someone else does it for me.