# How do I run Flask API in CA SSL?

Tags: python, ssl

I wrote an api using python flask and attached my proof of purchase, but the proof has three files server.cer、server.key、uca.cer

Currently flask only supports two files server.cer、server.key

But there is no way to put uca.cer

api will be considered unsafe by the web page

`from flask import Flask, abort, request, jsonify

app = Flask(**name**)

...

if **name** =='**main**':
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, ssl_context =('server.cer', 'server.key'))`

I tried using ssl_context =('server.cer', 'server.key', 'uca.cer')

but will fail

How can flask be added to uca.cer?

Comment: If the certicates are in PEM format (`-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----...`) you can simply put both into one file. If not convert them with `openssl`.

Comment: no PEM type，TWCA is all cer type.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991758/how-to-get-pem-file-from-key-and-crt-files